# In Out Stored Procedure PHP MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the below PHP code for storing details into a table by calling the stored procedure: I would prefer to have the code in procedural way

```
$donpm = 0;
$cashCall = mysqli_prepare($dbc, 'call spCashDonation(?,@rno)');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($cashCall, 'ssiid', $donFirstName, $donLastName, $donContactNo, $donpm, $donAmount);
mysqli_stmt_execute($cashCall) or die('Error recording Donation details.');

$getRno = mysqli_query($dbc, 'SELECT @rno');
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getRno);
$ReceiptNo = $result['@rno'];

echo $ReceiptNo;
```

Calling the Stored Procedure:

```
Call spCashDonation ('SAI','KUMAR',9967021655,0,10000,@rno);
select @rno as ReceiptNo;
```

I am not getting any output for the PHP code (Receipt No). For the first time I am writing a PHP code to call a procedure from MySQL.

Please advice

Comment: Please do also advice on the proper steps for calling a InOut Stored Procedure from PHP. Thanks

Comment: Let me suggest you to learn these things separately: first try prepared statements, then calling stored procedures with mysqli and then finally combine them together.

Comment: Thanks do you have a sample code or reference?

Comment: well, for such a general topics I just google for phrases like "calling stored procedures with mysqli", "working with prepared statements with mysqli" etc.

Comment: I did and most of the results are for pdo. If you don't want to help fine atleast dont demotivate by posting such. Rather it would have kind to post some reference links

Comment: you can always refine your google searches by adding "-pdo +mysqli" keywords, it will make search results more relevant

Comment: Thanks I learned to Google today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after doing some research, it seems the problem was with the `mysqli_prepare` statement: Incorrect parameters.

Below is the refined code:

```
$donpm = 0;
$cashCall = mysqli_prepare($dbc, 'call spCashDonation(?,?,?,?,?,@rno)');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($cashCall, 'ssiid', $donFirstName, $donLastName, $donContactNo, $donpm, $donAmount);
mysqli_stmt_execute($cashCall) or die('Error recording Donation details.');

$getRno = mysqli_query($dbc, 'SELECT @rno');
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getRno);
$ReceiptNo = $result['@rno'];

echo $ReceiptNo;
echo $donFirstName . ' ' . $donLastName . ' ' . $donContactNo . ' ' . $donpm . ' ' . $donAmount;
```